# AMD Loader disable, enable in theme

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dojo, xpages

I have a problem with the AMD Loader.
I want bind the bootstrap-slider.js and the css into the application. All the javascript and css are declare in a theme. Now the slider js don't harmonize with the dojo js.
I found the [explains](http://xomino.com/2015/06/08/fixing-the-xpages-r9-dojo-define-amd-problem-once-and-for-all/) from Marky Roden and the [XSnippet](http://openntf.org/xsnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=hack-to-use-jquery-amd-widgets-and-dojo-together) von Ferry Kranenburg. In the custom control the code is very good. But I want all that in the theme for all the application.
But it don't work. Can I disable, enable the AMD Loader in a theme?

Comment: Theoretically, with Ferry's snippet I'd say that it should work. Have you tried?

Comment: I cannot write this 
`code`<xp:this.contents><![CDATA[${javascript:"if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {if(define.amd.vendor =='dojotoolkit.org'){define._amd = define.amd;delete define.amd;}}";}]]></xp:this.contents>`code`
in a theme, or?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that's possible. Create 2 additional JavaScript files:

`disable_amd.js` with the following contents:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {if(define.amd.vendor =='dojotoolkit.org'){define._amd = define.amd;delete define.amd;}}
```

and

`enable_amd.js` with the following contents:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define._amd) {define.amd = define._amd; delete define._amd;}
```

Load the first one before you load `bootstrap-slider.js` JavaScript file (place it above that) and the second one afterwards.

Comment: Great idea! I will try it.